# AWT FileDialog фильтрация (MS Windows)

Tags: файлы, windows, awt, java

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Подскажите, как можно фильтровать файлы по расширению в `java.awt.FileDialog` если программа запущена в `MS WIndows`? В нескольких источниках читал, что под виндой этот метод не реализован...

Сейчас делаю так:

```
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(new Frame(), "Сохранить эскиз", FileDialog.SAVE);
fd.setFilenameFilter(new FilenameFilter() {
@Override
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return name.endsWith(".jpg");
}
});
fd.setFile("Эскиз.jpg");
fd.setVisible(true);`
```

Разумеется, под виндой не фильтрует, только под линуксом и маком...

Самое смешное, что в `accept()` директория и имя файла прилетают, но изменение результата вообще ни к чему не приводит.

Есть ли универсальный (мультиплатформенный) способ фильтровать файлы?

PS: `SWT` и `JNI` (`google xfiledialog`) не предлагать - не хочу тянуть с собой лишний груз.
Да, и `JFileChooser` тоже - не нравится он мне... :)
Спасибо!

Comment: Вобщем то странно что не фильтрует. Попробуй сделать проверку без учета регистра.

Comment: Пробовал я, разумеется. http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4031440 вот не единожды упоминалось.

Comment: @Евгений Карпов Указанный вами баг резолвнут в 2000 году. Баг гласит, что метод FilenameFilter.accept() не вызывается. Вы же сами говорите, что в accept() приходят правильные значения параметров. Не находите противоречия?

Comment: А Вы попробуйте в `.accept()` вызвать `System.out.println("accept");`

Тогда, быть может, и Вы не найдете противоречий.